# Sound Output Through 3.5mm With HDMI Connected

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have two monitors (ASUS VH238-C) and I am trying to get sound to play through both of them.

The current setup is as follows:

- Main monitor is connected through HDMI.
- Second monitor is connected through DVI.

If I set the main monitor up to play through the HDMI audio and use the recording stereo mixer trick to push the audio to the 2nd monitor, there is a delay that makes it too annoying to setup like this.

Instead, I am trying to make both monitors use their audio port to play the audio. However, with the main monitor, it refuses to accept audio from the audio jack while using HDMI for the video output.

Am I overlooking something simple? I cannot figure out what is preventing the main monitor from outputting the audio. I am 100% sure the cable and port are fine as, if I plug in my headphones, I can hear the audio fine. If I plug the cable into the 2nd monitor it works fine, just not to the main monitor.

To clarify, I am not looking to output audio from the monitors audio out jack!

I want to use the monitors speakers via the audio in jacks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution to a similar problem here:
http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2291085/sound-play-hdmi-monitor.html 
and
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-1776963/hdmi-monitor-playing-sound.html

But in case you actually did those and are getting audio through the 2nd monitor and not the 1st, I suspect it could be that your monitor and the graphics card are just not compatible. Try updating your video card / onboard audio drivers and test again.

Comment: I am not trying to play the audio through HDMI.

Comment: that is right, but in order to play sound from the 3.5mm at the back of your monitors which are connected via HDMI, it is necessary to ensure the monitor is detected as a HDMI sound output device. That will send the video and audio signals together out of the graphics card and into the monitor, which splits the signals to the screen (video) and 3.5mm(audio) where you actually plug your headphones into.

Comment: That is also not what I am trying to accomplish. I want to use the speaks of the monitor to output the sound via the audio in jacks on the monitor while using HDMI for the video.

Comment: Does your monitor support playing the audio from the HDMI signal through its speakers directly then? In that case you wont have to use the audio-in port on the monitor.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but I suggest you read my entire question first.. this is exactly the opposite thing I am trying to accomplish.